# Recursively enumerable set is an image of primitive recursive function

Tags: algorithms, recursion, computability

My definition of R.E set is that it is R.E if it is the image of some Partial Recursive Function. How can I show that if this set is definately non-empty then it is an image of Primitive Recursive Function?

Comment: What do you mean by "definately non-empty"?

Comment: that recursively enumerable set A has at least one element

Comment: I think what @RobertIsrael is asking is what the word "definitely" is doing there - how is "definitely non-empty" different from just "non-empty?"

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be nonempty and r.e.

Fix $a \in A$ and $f(x)$ partial recursive with image $A$.

Define a new function $F(x,n)$ where
$
F(x,n) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & f(x) \downarrow \text{in $\leq n$ steps}\\
a    & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Then $F$ is primitive recursive (cf. [Kleene's T Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate))
and has the same image as $f$.

So $A$ is the image of a primitive recursive function, as desired.

---

Hope this helps ^_^